# accept() change the server socket descriptor

Tags: c, sockets

I am implementing a simple socket. However, the server program occur a segmentation fault issue, and I found that after calling accept() function, the server socket descriptor was changed into wrong value. I attached a part of my code below. I can't find the reason that the value of socket descriptor was changed by accept() function. What's the problem with my code? Thanks.

```
while(1)
{
  readFdSet = allFdSet;

  // Call the select() function to check the change of input stream
  if(select(maxFd+1, &readFdSet, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
  {
    printf("Fail to select the fd\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  // Check the connection request to serverSocket
  if(FD_ISSET(serverSocket, &readFdSet))
  {
    // Accept the connection request from the client
    clientAddrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
    // It prints 'serverSocket: 3'
    printf("serverSocket: %d\n", serverSocket);
    clientSocket =  accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&clientSocket, &clientAddrSize);
    // It prints 'serverSocket: 16777343'
    printf("serverSocket: %d\n", serverSocket);

    if(clientSocket == -1)
    {
      printf("Fail to accept a client\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    else
      printf("Accept a client, fd = %d\n", clientSocket);

    // Add the fd of clientSocket into allFdSet
    FD_SET(clientSocket, &allFdSet);

    if(clientSocket > maxFd)
    {
      maxFd = clientSocket;
    }
    continue;
  }

  for(int i=0; i<=maxFd; i++)
  {
    clientSocket = i;
    if(FD_ISSET(clientSocket, &readFdSet))
    {
      // Read the message from the client 
      memset(buff, 0, BUFF_SIZE);
      while(read(clientSocket, buff, BUFF_SIZE)>0)
      {
        printf("%s", buff);
        memset(buff, 0, BUFF_SIZE);
      }

      close(clientSocket);
      FD_CLR(clientSocket, &allFdSet);

      if(maxFd == clientSocket)
        maxFd--;

      printf("Close the connection\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where does the SEGFAULT happen when you run your program in a debugger?

Comment: 1) `while(read(clientSocket, buff, BUFF_SIZE)>0)` read() can return zero. Use the return value, Luke!  2) Also: `printf("%s", buff);` assumes a nul-terminated string. 3) And: after select() returns readable, you can call read() **one time**, without blocking. 4) And: read() and select() can return -1 for EAGAIN, EINTR

Comment: Why do you pass `accept` `clientSocket`, but the size of `clientAddr`? Or is `clientAddr` the type of `clientSocket`? If you had posted a [mcve], we'd not have questions like this ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
clientSocket =  accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&clientSocket, &clientAddrSize);
```

The problem is here. `clientSocket` is an FD, not a `sockaddr`, and it doesn't have its size, i.e. `sizeof(clientAddr)`. So `accept()` will corrupt whatever lies before or after `clientSocket`, which could well be `serverSocket`, or anything else.

It should be:

```
clientSocket =  accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr, &clientAddrSize);
```

As first hinted at by @ChrisTurner.